# Reading/Writing salvaged EEPROM

Tags: arduino-uno, eeprom

Recently I stumbled myself on a fairly old blood sugar test strips canisters. Inside them, I found this what they called "Code Card" which inside, an EEPROM `Microchip 93LC46B` a `1K Microwire compatible serial EEPROM`. I want to salvage them for my Arduino project. Is possible to read/write data to them? and how to determine the capacity? I only see `16 bit word size` on the datasheet and `1K` on the title.

Comment: Page 1 of the datasheet: `The Microchip Technology Inc. 93XX46A/B/C devices
are 1Kbit low-voltage serial Electrically Erasable
PROMs (EEPROM). ` - in what way is that vague?

Comment: Yes you can use it with Arduino. You just have to *read* the datasheet.

Comment: @Majenko Didn't notice that but thanks

Comment: BTW, MicroWire is almost like SPI, but CS is active high not active low.